# Getting Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc (default-cli)

Tags: java, maven, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have an XSD file and I'm trying to generate jaxb classes for that using jaxb2-maven plugin, the problem I generate the classes running the command `mvn jaxb2:xjc` in command line. If I run the same command as goal in run configuration in eclipse I get

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc
>   (default-cli)

If I only run `mvn clean package install` the classes are not getting generated. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my part of pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
    <schemaFiles>Trans.xsd</schemaFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Running maven with debug mode might show some helpful message.

Comment: Updating the version to 2.5.0 should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a `phase` element in your `execution` configuration like this :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
    <schemaFiles>Trans.xsd</schemaFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

By doing that, your maven will execute the `xjc` goal when validating your project